# ui_xprotolabinterface.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, github

I'm trying to build the Xscope interface for the Gabotronics xprotolab digital oscilloscope chip. I found the latest user interface tool on [github](https://github.com/ewisuri/xscopes-qt) and I cloned it. I followed [these instructions](https://www.gabotronics.com/component/option,com_ccboard/Itemid,12/forum,15/topic,314/view,postlist/) to build the GUI on my Linux machine which is running Ubuntu 14.04.

Everything was going well until I typed `make` and I got the following error -

```
fatal error: ui_xprotolabinterface.h: No such file or directory
     #include "ui_xprotolabinterface.h"
```

So I began to search for ui_xprotolabinterface.h and I couldn't find it anywhere! I removed the `#include "ui_xprotolabinterface.h"` line from the `xprotolabinterface.cpp` file (where these errors were originating from) and I get even more errors without it.

I checked the github source to see if there was an updated version of the code, but this is the most updated version...

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: These `ui_*.h` files are generated by Qt's `uic` tool from `*.ui` files. If setup correctly, CMake calls `uic` to produce these auto-generated headers. I assume that either their CMake file is broken or that there are other errors prior to that _no such fule or directory_.

Comment: I got the GUI to work another way. So I'm not gonna go over this approach. Thanks though!